# C++ memory usage and reduce

Tags: c++, memory

How many bytes of memory does this simple program utilize?

```
#include<iostream> 

int main()
{
    int a, b; 
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a+b;
}
```

Why? What would be the best way to reduce the amount of memory in a program like this?

Comment: SO isn't here to do your homework for you. At least provide something you've thought of, or any ideas you have about the question.

Comment: Highly depended on OS, platform, compiler, standard library.

Comment: It doesn't use a significant amount of memory, and therefore, there's no point in reducing the amount of memory.

Comment: Impossible to answer without very specific information about your system, tools and their settings. The best way to get the information is to compile the code and look at the compiler generated files, e.g. map file. Putting compiler optimization to highest level would be one way to reduce the memory used.

Comment: Which "kind" of memory? Stack, heap, code, data? Which one do you want to reduce?

Comment: @MatsPetersson RAM memory

Comment: That's not a very precise answer, as "RAM" is pretty much the only memory you have in any reasonably modern system. Flash/ROM is rarely used for much other than as storage for applications and operating system.

Comment: @qqwertyyy: Don't repost an exact duplicate when the first one is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The question has **no precise answer as asked**. You will not get an answer in the vein of "134 bytes" at all.

The program may utilize :

1. Memory storing the executable code.
2. Memory storing variables `a` and `b`. Several kinds of memory may be used, like registers or RAM banks.
3. Memory for startup code, unused heap, unused stack and maybe even for unused facilities like `errno` or program arguments.
4. Memory utilized by libraries utilized by the program.
5. Memory utilized by the operating system and drivers under which the program is run if any.
6. Memory, registers and associates caches used by the graphics card used by the program. Or a printer if output goes to a printer, or whatever.
7. Memory and registers used by the keyboard and motherboard's keyboard controller or by whatever device is used for input.
8. Memory to store subrutine return directions and parameters.
9. CPU registers like the Program counter.
10. Memory used by the Virtual Machine or the emulator under which the operating system (or lack of it) which runs your program is running. And here the whole story begins again and it can span as many layers as resources allow.
11. Caches used by many of the previous subsystems.
12. And many things else I have not considered. If the program runs in a system powered by UPS then its memory, if any, might or might not be required for the program being able to run, the list could go on for a lot longer.

Many of those memories are used by the program as evidenced by the fact that the program will not work if the memory of such subsystem is removed. Some might actually be optional and the program might actually run without them depending on the system, but in any case its going to use many of them.
And even if you restrict your question to some of those subsystems the answer will be different for different computer architectures. And even for the same architecture the answer will be different for different compilers or even for the same compiler with different parameters.

**Conclusion :**
Even such a simple program is run on top of a very complex system of software and hardware.
To get a precise answer you need to make a precise question.
You may be interested in reading about [C++ Internals :: Memory Layout](http://www.gahcep.com/cpp-internals-memory-layout/)